# Destroy if multiselect has already inited

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-multiselect

I will call `initProductSelect` which inits a jquery ui's multiselect

```
$handler.multiselect({...})
```

But I found some problem when secondly call ``initProductSelect`, without destroy, but if I call handler.multiselect('destroy').multiselect({...}) the very first time I call`initProductSelect`, error will occur since it is not inited yet, I search for doc http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget but not find an method like "isInit".

Do I have to store a variable returns from `var $multiselect=$handler.multiselect({...})` some where globally, and check `if($multiselect==null)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the element, something like "alreadyInited" to know that it was initalized, and skip the init for that. Like:

```
 function initProductSelect() {
  if $handler.hasClass("alreadyInited") return;
  else $handler.multiselect({...})
 }
```

Comment: What is `else` doing here?

Comment: else is initializing your multiselect if it wasn't already initialized